# Brackets/curly brackets highlighting in code samples

Tags: feature-request, code

I wonder if in code samples we can highlight the closing bracket when the opening bracket is clicked (and vice versa).

This can sound like a silly feature but it does help a lot visually to quickly rule out small coding mistakes in the snippets. I am used to that in my editors and I unintentionally look for it when reviewing code on SO.

**Update 1**
This is not only about preventing questions with trivial syntax issues, this is about aiding readers in understanding the code snippets by visually highlighting where every block starts and ends. I do this now by copying the code snippet into an external IDE and examine it. It would be more convenient if I can do this in place inside SO, I am just a developer being lazy.

Comment: Interesting idea. Likely tough to implement though. Perhaps prettify.js (which is currently used to format the code nicely) could be extended to support it?

Comment: you'd basically have to implement a parse for every language where you want support, but I could be wrong, how do generic editors like Notepad++ do it?

Comment: Are you asking for an editor feature or a syntax highlighting feature?

Comment: A naive language-ignorant approach to matching parens/braces/brackets would probably be correct in 95% of cases, and potentially very useful. That error rate is probably good enough for ephemeral focused highlighting like this. I really like the idea.

Comment: Seems pointless. Any nontrivial code (i.e. the kind where such errors aren't easy to see) should probably not be written online, but copy pasted from the editor or IDE of your choice. Not using those tools for things like brace highlighting, static analysis, compilation, etc, is wasting them.

Comment: Unix shell script has a `case` syntax with unmatched right parentheses `case $a in foo) echo "Here";; esac` (though POSIX mandates a newer syntax which allows them: `case $a in (foo) echo "Here";; esac`). This is Bourne shell and derivatives.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I will take a look at prettify to see if it can be (or already) extended to support that. I did not know that prettify was powering SO here.

Comment: @Bergi it is in between, I do not want to edit the code but I want when I click on an open bracket, it highlights its closing one.

Comment: @Dannnno I completely agree that the best way to go is to use an editor/IDE. But a part of understanding code is to be able to determine scopes and where functions starts and ends, specially with languages that use plenty of brackets like Javascript, it is hard to do that now in SO snippets, you have to trace it visually which can be hard, or you have to copy the code sample out of SO into an IDE which takes a bit of effort. It would be best if this can be done in place inside SO. That's my point

Answer (score 11):

Sure, it would be great to have this feature.  But it would also be nice if we could perform static analysis on our code.  And if it could refactor the code for us too that would be great.  And maybe support for a couple of different compilers and interpreters.  While we're on that route, maybe the ability to add breakpoints and debug the code?

While that is (hopefully) obviously silly and taken to an extreme, it illustrates the kind of road I suspect that this would be taken on.  We don't need these features because **we have tools that do them already**, and if you aren't using those tools to write non-trivial code (read as: code where parens/brackets/braces aren't obviously (in)correct) then you're doing something wrong.

To address [a specific point in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314456/brackets-curly-brackets-highlighting-in-code-samples?noredirect=1#comment293361_314456):

> But a part of understanding code is to be able to determine scopes and where functions starts and ends, specially with languages that use plenty of brackets like Javascript, it is hard to do that now in SO snippets, you have to trace it visually which can be hard, or you have to copy the code sample out of SO into an IDE which takes a bit of effort.

I can empathize with this to an extent, however I don't think this is the right solution to the problem.  I see two sources of the actual problem here:

1. The code is poorly formatted (which may very well be what caused the bug they're asking about) in which case it may merit editing and/or down-votes (or close-votes if it is a silly typographic error that was hidden by bad formatting).
2. The code is complex enough where there are a lot of parens/brackets/braces, which leads to the confusion.  This isn't necessarily bad, but can often be a sign that the question hasn't really been made into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) yet, in which case it probably merits editing (by the poster) or down-votes (by everyone).

Otherwise, in a well-formatted and written piece of code that is also an SSCCE, I've never really had an issue with matching parens/braces/brackets for the sake of understanding.

---

Besides that, there is the issue of language compatibility.  As [also mentioned in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314456/brackets-curly-brackets-highlighting-in-code-samples?noredirect=1#comment293354_314483):

> Not all languages always have balanced brackets or parentheses. Think about bash: `case "$1" in start)...`

I think that it would be difficult/annoying to make this work in all cases, and posts with multiple language tags could be tricky too.

Answer (score -6):

I think it's a good idea that could help with reading and understanding code.

But as far as an aid in reviewing code for trivial syntax errors, why not cut out the middle man and alert the  OP of mismatched, incorrect or missing brackets, parentheses and line-enders when they ask their question. Thus eliminating the need to answer questions with trivial syntax issues.

Comment: No, that won't work. Not all languages always have balanced brackets or parentheses. Think about bash: `case "$1" in start)...`

Comment: I agree that this won't work, it is not only about minimising questions with trivial syntax issues, it is about visually aiding me to understand the piece of code in the question (knowing scopes, where functions starts and ends, etc). I usually do this now by copy the sample from SO to an external IDE, and I'd love if it can be done in place in SO.